# Inaccurate aggregation return of double values in complex data structures

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

When I use the aggregation framework to get values from my database and I got complex data structures, such as arrays of struct with doubles, I get inaccurate values.

I use the ToList() on my `IAsyncCursor` to get my values. The double values should be such as `13.23` and in the return json string the values are like `13.2300000001` or something like that. This is just a behavior if I use this complex structures of data.

What can I do against this Inaccuracy? Am I using the false classes and methods of the csharp api?

Comment: "What can I do against this Inaccuracy" - never directly compare two floats for equality. Always with some epsilon.

Comment: I think, this doesn't explain why the mongodb c# api shows up that behavior.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you try the same thing in mongodb shell, you'll get similar results. This is just how floating point numbers work, fundamentally, in every language.

Comment: Try this in your console: `Console.WriteLine((0.1 + 0.2) == 0.3);`

Comment: `'{ "Name" : "Some Name Value", "Value" : 123.63, "Child" : { "Name" : "Single Child", "Value" : 0.123, "arr" : [12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0] }, "Children" : [{ "Name" : "Child1", "Value" : 1.123, "arr" : [12.1, 13.1, 14.1, 15.1] }, { "Name" : "Child2", "Value" : 2.1230000000000002, "arr" : [12.199999999999999, 13.199999999999999, 14.199999999999999, 15.199999999999999] }, { "Name" : "Child3", "Value" : 3.1230000000000002, "arr" : [12.300000000000001, 13.300000000000001, 14.300000000000001, 15.300000000000001] }] }'`

- does that really explain that inconsistent behavior of mongodbs `ToList()`?

Comment: Why do you keep insisting that `ToList()` is the culprit? How do you _know_?

Comment: Maybe I should use another more recommended method... What I don't understand is, that some double values are read "correctly" (Child)1 and others are not (Child2 or Child3)
child2 should be: `{ "Name" : "Child2", "Value" : 2.123, "arr" : [12.2, ...`

Thanks for your replies btw, helped me to understand it so far.

Comment: Some floating point numbers can be represented "exactly", others can not. That's what you observe here. Also, _do_ read the linked topic.

Comment: Okay now I got it, thanks a lot.
It's the numbers I choose, not the structure of my json.